# IIS 6.0 Restart mandatory if AppPool Identity is changed?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

Could anyone please confirm whether we must start IIS if we changed the AppPool Identity after doing below:

1. Add Identity Account to  IIS_WPG Group.

I tried restarting the AppPool but did not work. Error with  "Service Not Available"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that the AppPool is running? Sometime, after you changed the identity, the app pool appears running, but it is not. i.e. after you restart it, it shows a picture with a dot, i.e. it could not be restarted. This could happen when pool identity password expired or when the password is not entered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the identity of the Application pool, IIS should reset that application pool automatically and try to run itself as the new identity

If you're only changing the permissions of the identity, those permissions should just be picked up, no need to reset the application pool at that point

Comment: Thanks but IIS 6.0  did not reset. I had to restart IIS manually, not sure why

Comment: oh sorry, that probably is the case with IIS6, I'm so used to IIS7 lately